# modification of rows instead of columns in a table

Tags: javascript, dom

I have such a table

```
<table><tr>
<td>some code</td>
<td>some code</td>
<td>some code</td>
</table>
```

How to modify it to

```
<table><tr>
<td>some code</td>
<tr><td>some code</td>
<tr><td>some code</td>
</table>
```

with Javascript?

Comment: You should close your <tr> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableid");
var oldrow = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
var cells = oldrow.childNodes;
while (cells.length>0) {
 var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
 table.appendChild(newrow);
 newrow.appendChild(cells[0]);
}
table.removeChild(oldrow);
```